# Best practice on how to create a daemon thread to monitor a map

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, daemon

I have a class with a static map which keeps on updated randomly.

```
class MyMap{
private static Map my_map= new Map();
//setters
//getters
}
```

I want to create MapObserver class which spawn daemon thread once. This thread calls a method which reads the map.

```
class MapObserver{
private static boolean initialised = false;
private static final ScheduledExecutorService exec = 
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory() {

        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }
    });
public static void startObserverThread() {
        if (!initialised) {
            exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //read method
                }

            }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            initialised=true;
        }
    }
}
```

How and where to initialize this class so that it initializes only once and no extra threads are spawned.
Is this a good way to monitor my map.

Comment: if this is a singleton, make the class `final` and it's constructor `private`. Else it looks more like it belongs on the [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: yes i made it singleton. But how to initialize this class? (only once)

Comment: You might want to use `static-initializer-blocks` or you can just call `startObserverThread` In your `main`-method

Comment: you may create a static getter to return the singleton instance, there you can initialize the singleton object (or search for the static initializer block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a static Map, you can simply place a static ([singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/java/1))  Thread or your MapObserver

regardless that your question will get downvoted as what you've described is a very bad way to monitor an object state.  Please read and learn the [design patterns](https://www.journaldev.com/1827/java-design-patterns-example-tutorial)

The proper way maybe would creating a facade (a Map subclass overriding the `put` method notifying what needs to be notified), if someone has a better idea, feel free to comment.

If you have a use case which would limit you this option or forcing you use a separate thread (not considering locking etc), you will need to specify it in your question

Comment: I dont need to monitor the updating of the map. The value in the map is a time and whenever that time is less than current time i need to pop an alert. Thus i have to use a seprate thread and iterate over the map to know what time has exceeded.